# How to check if different props are equal in Ramda?

Tags: ramda.js

How would I go about checking if first and last are equivalent here?

```
const obj = {
    first: 5,
    last: 5,
}
```

This is a small part of a much bigger problem which I will paste here just for posterity:

```
[
    { first: 5, last: 5, things: [{id: null, item: null} ] },
    { first: 10, last: 15, things:[
        {id: null, item: 10}, {id: null, item: 13}, {id: null, item: 14} 
    ]}
]
```

Essentially I need this data distilled down to this:

```
[[5], [10,13,14]]
```

And essentially to do this I'll need some conditional logic, either to see if a top level object has item as null, or (what seems easier) if first and last are equal. If first and last are equal, grab any of their numbers, else map over "things" and return the items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to jump through a few hoops to get it pointfree! Would definitely benefit from splitting out into smaller functions in a real scenario too.

```
map(
   ifElse(
     compose(apply(equals), props(['first', 'last'])),
     compose(of, prop('first')),
     compose(pluck('item'), prop('things'))
   )
 )(input)
```

Comment: `map(prop('item'))` might be more conveniently expressed `pluck('item')`.

Comment: Edited - I'll do it right _and_ beat you to it one of these days ;)

Comment: Also, is there a great reason to make the predicate points-free?  Either of these reads better to me: `obj => obj.first == obj.last` or `obj => equals(obj.first, obj.last)`.

Comment: Hey, I've been doing Ramda since before Ramda started, quite literally.  I'm one of the original authors.  (Not that there aren't others who know more about it than I do.)  But there was nothing really wrong with your answer, just a slightly easier way to do it.  I just think it's great to see others answering Ramda questions.

Comment: Funnily enough I've been watching begriffs/drbooleans fp course lately, in which they still point to `crosseye/ramda` ;)

Comment: Re pointfree - I figured because the author asked specifically _in ramda_, I'm not sure I'd even use the pointfree solution myself. Of course we know what they say about assumptions..

Comment: And before that there was `crosseye/eweda`, which didn't really meet its goals of being practical...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156115/discussion-between-ross-mackay-and-scott-sauyet).

Comment: Thanks for all the comments guys. Great conversation. Even the fact that you originally used map(prop('item')) then subsequently used pluck from the follow up suggestion was pretty helpful... now I can discard my overt usage of map + prop knowing those are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this, I know its old, but still useful.

The equivalency test can be handled much easier now with the `converge` function:

`converge(equals, [prop('first'), prop('last')])`

To do a generic equality of 2 props, you could do:

`const propsEq = R.compose(R.apply(R.equals), R.props)`

Although this results in a non-curried function (you must supply the array containing the 2 props to test and the object at the same time).
I'm sure there is a better way...